# Yii . Создание таблиц в БД.

Tags: ооп, php, yii

Требуется создать новую таблицу в БД, при переходе на страницу index.php/order/db .
Создал контролер order и в нем активное действие db с кодом:

```
CDbMigration::createTable('orders', '5');
```

Ничего не получилось. Нужно вставить вот это:

```
// Create table
$sql="CREATE TABLE $histori_db
(   
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'код истории',  
nomer INT COMMENT 'номер заказа',   
delo VARCHAR(280) COMMENT 'дело',   
who VARCHAR(280) COMMENT 'кем', 
kogda VARCHAR(30) COMMENT 'время',  
PRIMARY KEY (id)    
)";
```

В чем дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполнить произвольный sql

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
```

Создать таблицу через миграцию

```
$migration->createTable('tablename', array(
    'column1' => 'integer AUTO_INCREMENT',
    'column2' => 'varchar(64)',
));
```

> Требуется создать новую таблицу в БД, при переходе на страницу index.php/order/db

*запятая не нужна, ну ё-моё,* без подробностей наверняка не сказать, но на 95% это неверная архитектура и никакой новой таблицы создавать не надо.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось. Поясните, что значит "на 95% это неверная архитектура"? т.е. так не делается? А как? через модель. Просто в большинстве обучающих уроков создают через phpMyAdmin, но мне хотелось бы, чтобы при установки сайта с нуля, все Таблицы создавались одним кликом.

Comment: @Максим147, 95% что вам не нужно создавать дополнительнуютабоицу в рантайме. Скорее в его те данные, которые вы собираетесь хранить в этих таблицах могут быть сохранены в одной. Создание структуры таблиц производится через миграции, которые запускаются их консоли, т.е. контроллером там и не пахло.